# im tring to install the wordpress on the docker-compose.yml but not working

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose

This is the code I have tried but not working. is there any better code available there installation of the Wordpress in the docker-compose?

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Services:

web:

image: wordpress

ports:
- 80:80

environment:

WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db"
WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "root"

WORDPRESS DB PASSWORD: "Password"
WORDPRESS DB NAME: "wordpress"
db:

image: mysql

expose:
-3306

environment:

MYSQL ROOT PASSWORD: "Password"

MYSQL DATABASE: "wordpress"